# Having an object merge two functions and passing them as a callback? (C++)

Tags: c++, interrupt, arduino-c++

I'd like to have my class take a function "the callback stub", add some stuff that processes before and after the stub, and then pass the whole thing as a callback to an interrupt. Different stubs could be attached to different instances of the class.

I'm getting errors as shown in the comments below. It works to take a function pointer, store it as an attribute, and then pass it to the attachInterrupt function. However, it doesn't work to add the little prelude.

In **setInterrupt()**, I get **a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the functionC/C++(300)**

**altSetInterrupt()** however compiles fine.

**Question:** Is there a combination of * & or -> that can make this work?

EDITED: to remove a silly mistake as pointed out by Jerry Jeremiah

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#define MYPIN 1

// Declarations
class myClass {
    public:
    myClass();
    void setInterrupt();
    void altSetInterrupt();
    void setCallBackStub( void (*cb)());

    private:
    void (*myCallBackStub)();
    void myCallBack();
};

void mySillyCB();

// Definitions
myClass::myClass():
    myCallBackStub(nullptr)
    {}

void myClass::setCallBackStub( void (*cb)()) {
    myCallBackStub = cb;
}

void myClass::myCallBack() {
    Serial.println("Wohoo");
    myCallBackStub(); 
}


void myClass::setInterrupt() {
    attachInterrupt(MYPIN, this->myCallBack, HIGH); // a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the functionC/C++(300)
}

void myClass::altSetInterrupt() {
    attachInterrupt(MYPIN, this->myCallBackStub, HIGH); // no compiler error here
}


void mySillyCB() {
    Serial.println("Called Back");
}

// Code
myClass theThing;

void setup() {
    theThing.setCallBackStub( mySillyCB);
    theThing.setInterrupt();
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: The `"myCallBackStub" is undefinedC/C++(20)` erroir is because myCallback is defined as a free function `void myCallBack() {` and not a member function `void myClass::myCallBack() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In myCallBack(), I get identifier "myCallBackStub" is undefinedC/C++(20)

You have defined this as a free function rather than implementing a method.  You have:

```
void myCallBack() {
```

But you should have:

```
void myClass::myCallBack() {
```

Because of this, there is no such name `myCallBackStub` in scope.

> In setInterrupt(), I get a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the functionC/C++(300)

`this->myCallBack` is not a first-class value in C++; it is a member function that is bound to a particular instance (`*this`). The only thing you can do with this is invoke it (like `this->myCallBack()`).

Notably, you cannot convert it to a function pointer. This is because non-static member functions need an instance on which to invoke the function, and a free function pointer (what `attachInterrupt` accepts) has no additional mechanism to convey this state. Even if you used the correct syntax for a pointer-to-member-function (`&myClass::myCallBack`) this still would not work since you cannot convert between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-member-function.

You *can* pass `this->myCallBackStub` because this is actually a function pointer value.

---

Since `attachInterrupt()` state is global anyway, you don't gain a whole lot by *not* making your mechanism global. The primary challenge you are running into is that the callback function accepts no arguments so you can't even tell which pin/mode was used.

To get around this, you need a different non-member callback function per pin/mode combination, and these must be known *in advance* at compile time, since you (presumably) don't want to get into the complexity of emitting trampolines at runtime.

This can be done at compile time with the use of macros. Each invocation of the macro should do several things:

- Declare a global callback function.
- Declare a global vector of callback function objects that will be invoked by the global callback function.
- Possibly invoke `attachInterrupt()` depending on whether this can be done during static initialization.

Here is a sample implementation of this concept, which may need tweaking to be useful in production.  You would create a header like `interrupts.hpp` with the following:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

// These types may need adjusting to match Arduino's types.
using Pin_t = int;
using Mode_t = int;

using InterruptCallback_t = std::function<void()>;
using InterruptCallbackList_t = std::vector<InterruptCallback_t>;

using RawInterruptCallback_t = void (*)();

#define DECLARE_INTERRUPT(pin, mode) DECLARE_INTERRUPT_(pin, mode)
#define DECLARE_INTERRUPT_(pin, mode) \
    void add_interrupt_callback_##pin##_##mode (InterruptCallback_t);

DECLARE_INTERRUPT(0, 0)
// And so on...
```

Then in the implementation file `interrupts.cpp`:

```
#include <utility>

#include "interrupts.hpp"

static void apply_interrupt_callback(InterruptCallbackList_t const & cbList) {
    for (const auto & cb : cbList) {
        cb();
    }
}

#define IMPLEMENT_INTERRUPT(pin, mode) IMPLEMENT_INTERRUPT_(pin, mode)
#define IMPLEMENT_INTERRUPT_(pin, mode) \
    static InterruptCallbackList_t generated_interrupt_callbacks_##pin##_##mode ; \
    static void generated_interrupt_callback_##pin##_##mode() { \
        apply_interrupt_callback( generated_interrupt_callbacks_##pin##_##mode ); \
    } \
    void add_interrupt_callback_##pin##_##mode (InterruptCallback_t cb) { \
        ( generated_interrupt_callbacks_##pin##_##mode ).emplace_back(std::move(cb)); \
    } \
    static int generated_interrupt_registration_##pin##_##mode = ( \
        attachInterrupt(pin, generated_interrupt_callback_##pin##_##mode, mode), \
        0 \
    );

IMPLEMENT_INTERRUPT(0, 0)
// And so on...
```

This will generate a set of functions and global variables for each pin/mode combination you provide. The interface provided by `interrupts.hpp` will expose `add_interrupt_callback_N_M` where `N` and `M` are the pin and mode constants, respectively. You can pass any function or functor (with the help of `std::function<void()>` to this function and it will be called when the interrupt occurs.

Note that there is no mutex in this example code. For the sake of simplicity, I assume a single-threaded environment, where an interrupt callback cannot occur preemptively. The code will need to be changed if these assumptions are not true.

Comment: Thanks! I updated to remove the Identifier undefined error since it is irrelevant to the actual question. 

Do I understand your answer correctly if I say there is no way to accomplish what I want because there is a difference between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-member?

Comment: @BjornEriksson See my updated answer. Basically, since you can't convey state through the interrupt callback, everything has to be global. But you could use macros to make implementing all of the global state that you need less painful.

Comment: Thank you very much for this amazing answer. I really appreciate it! My application isn't complex enough to need the macro factory, but your approach has inspired me to implement something quick and simple in the same vein. Thanks!